# how to replace String array value with another value in java

Tags: java, android

```
String[] Arr_InfraId;   
List<String> List_infraid = new ArrayList<String>();

Arr_InfraId = List_infraid.toArray(new String[List_infraid.size()]);
```

This is my String array and values in String array I am getting `1,2,3,4...10` respectively I want replace all values `A,B,C,.....j` respectively and store in String array like `1->A,2->b,3->c........10->j`. Please tell me how to replace this I am getting `null Pointer exception` when I trying to got loop and try to replace it.

Comment: you should add some elements in your array list. Add some data in arraylist and then check.

Comment: You also haven't initialized `String[] Arr_InfraId;`. I suspect you should do that

Comment: Improve formatting and grammar correction

Comment: *I am getting null Pointer exception when I trying to got loop and try to replace it.* Okay Please show us the stackTrace and code.

Comment: @Boggartfly your suspicion is wrong.

Comment: Your initialization Arr_InfraId = List_infraid.toArray(new String[List_infraid.size()]);  looks fine, if you are iterating on Arr_InfraId you shouldn't get a NPE. So please paste the stacktrace.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/ib3mEd8kk8UybP5U5tiGxx  @Task look this code i am trying in this way

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment You have part of your code in your question, and part of it at some other site.  First of all, we have to guess how the two parts fit together.  Second, StackOverflow isn't just to get your own questions answered, it's meant to be a resource for those who might have the same kind of questions later.  For that reason, you really need to put all your code in the question, instead on another web site, unless it's really large.

Comment: @ajb Okay If I'm wrong would you please care to explain why? Enlighten us! :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with declaring a variable without an initializer, as long as you assign something to it before you use it.  And the OP's code does exactly that--it assigns a value into `Arr_InfraId` before the code uses it.  Because of that, the lack of an initializer on the declaration is irrelevant.  (I suspect the code is initializing it to the _wrong_ value, but without seeing the whole code I can't tell.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main {
static String [] string1 = {
        "1","2",
        "3","4",
        "5","6",
        "7","8",
        "9","10"};

static ArrayList<String> as = new ArrayList<String>();
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(int i =0;i<string1.length;i++){
        getArray(string1[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(as.toString());
}

public static void  getArray(String string){
    switch (string) {
    case "2":
        as.add("A");
        break;
    case "3":
        as.add("B");
        break;
    case "4":
        as.add("C");
        break;
    case "5":
        as.add("D");
        break;
    case "6":
        as.add("F");
        break;
    case "7":
        as.add("G");
        break;
    case "8":
        as.add("H");
        break;
    case "9":
        as.add("I");
        break;
    case "10":
        as.add("J");
        break;

    default:
        break;
       }
    }
}
```